# F# Silverlight 3.0 Custom Control Property throws: NullReferenceException

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, f#, custom-controls

I have defined a Control with:

```
 static member ItemsProperty : DependencyProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Items",
            typeof<MyMenuItemCollection>,
            typeof<MyMenu>,
            null);

 member this.Items
        with get () : MyMenuItemCollection = this.GetValue(MyMenu.ItemsProperty) :?> MyMenuItemCollection
        and set (value: MyMenuItemCollection) = this.SetValue(MyMenu.ItemsProperty, value);
```

The problem occurs on access:

```
for menuItem in this.Items do
    let contentElement: FrameworkElement = menuItem.Content
```

where I get a **null reference exception** on this.Items;

> 'Items' threw an exception of type
>   'System.NullReferenceException'

Immediately after I initialized in the constructor:

```
do
    this.Items <- new CoolMenuItemCollection()
```

Comment: Hi, this is not a discussion forum as much as a place for questions and answers. Assume anyone viewing your post has NOT read your "previous post"

Comment: true enough - guilty of typing aloud. Previous post is completely irrelavent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `static member` in F# doesn't correspond to public field as you may have expected, but to a property with `get` member. This means, that each time you acccess `this.ItemsProperty`, you're actually creating a new dependency property.

You can create a static field like this:

```
type Control = 
  // private static field
  static let itemsProperty : DependencyProperty =  
    DependencyProperty.Register
      ("Items", typeof<MyMenuItemCollection>, typeof<MyMenu>, null); 
  // public static property with getter 
  static member ItemsProperty = itemsProperty  

  // You can use both private 'itemsProperty' field or public property here
  member this.Items 
    with get () : MyMenuItemCollection = 
      this.GetValue(itemsProperty) :?> MyMenuItemCollection 
    and set (value: MyMenuItemCollection) = 
      this.SetValue(itemsProperty, value)
```

Comment: It fixed the NullReference exception. I think I will need to research the static modifer in F# a little more; control still isn't rendering output - but I am moving forward.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The CLR getter is NOT called by most of the framework. That is for the convienience of developer access is code behind files.

Inside your constructor would be a great place to initialize the collection if you need to.

Do NOT set a default value (null in your dependency property declaration above) to an empty collection. The default value is a shared, single static instance - so every instance of your control would share that same list, not what you are intending.

Comment: Thank you; I am refamiliarizing myself with .NET by writing a silverlight application in 100% F#.  Its proving to be a bigger project than expected.  DependencyProperty.Register shows two signatures on MSDN - however my intellisense is only showing a single signature, that takes four parameters.  Am I missing something? Or could that be F# mixing the sigs?

Comment: That shouldn't matter - your dependency property Register statement is already correct.

Comment: That is what I thought originally but I am having issues as the code as stated is throwing the NullReference exception... SO I think somehting must be off